# Получение данных из input для отправки в whatsapp

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, input, whatsapp

Есть скрипт который отправляет сообщение в whatsapp

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
// URL для запроса POST /message
    var url = 'https://eu43.chat-api.com/instance**********/message?token=**********';
    var data = {
        phone: '7**********', // Телефон получателя
        body:  'Здесь должно быть сообщение', // Сообщение
    };
    // Отправим запрос при нажатии на кнопку
    $( ".button" ).click(function() {
    $.ajax(url, {
        data : JSON.stringify(data),
        contentType : 'application/json',
        type : 'POST'
    });
    });
});
</script>
```

И есть input которые заполняются клиентом для отправки информации о заказе подключенным партнерам (кафе, рестораны) по номеру телефона в whatsapp для формирования и доставки заказа

```
<input name="name" class="t-input">
<input name="phone" class="t-input">
<input name="address" class="t-input">
<input type="hidden" name="recipient" value="7**********"> //Номер телефона получателя информации о заказе в whatsapp
```

Теперь задача - нужно отправлять информацию о заказе в whatsapp, которая содержится в значениях input (name,phone,address) на номер получателя (recipient) и перед каждым значением input (кроме recipient) поставить названия, то есть Имя:, Номер телефона:, Адрес: с новой строки. Значение recipient (получатель) нужно вставить в **phone**, а остальные input (name,phone,address) в **data**.

Пример получаемого сообщения:

- Имя: Дмитрий
- Телефон: +79999999999
- Адрес: Казань, улица Баумана, дом 20, квартира 19
- Заказ: Пицца "Маргарита"

Comment: Задача понятна. В чем проблема-то?

Comment: Вставлял в массив скрипт data = $(' .t-input[name="name"] ').val(); но информация не отправлялась, поэтому задаю вопрос как правильно решить задачу

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// Отправить запрос при нажатии на кнопку
$(".button").click(function() {
$.ajax('https://eu43.chat-api.com/instance**********/message?token=**********', {
  data: JSON.stringify({
    phone: $('input[name="recipient"]').val(),
    body: 
    `Имя: ${$('input[name="name"]').val()}\n`+
    `Телефон: ${$('input[name="phone"]').val()}\n`+
    `Адрес: ${$('input[name="address"]').val()}\n`+
    `Заказ: Pizza " Margarita"`
  }),
  contentType: 'application/json',
  type: 'POST'
});
});
});
```